# Before UPDATE Trigger PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have the following tables:

Battles - Name is PK

| Name | B_date |
| --- | --- |
| Battle1 | 01-JAN-1989 |
| Battle2 | 23-AUG-1996 |

Consequences - (Ship, Battle) is UK and Battle is FK to Battles

| Ship | Battle | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ShipX | Battle1 | unharmed |
| ShipX | Battle2 | unharmed |

I have to create a trigger that stops the updating of Result column to 'destroyed' if the ship participated in a battle that took place after the current battle. For example, I shouldn't be able to update the result to 'destroyed' in the row (ShipX, Battle1) in table Consequences, because ShipX also participated in Battle2 which took place after Battle1.

In order to check if ShipX has participated in other battles that took place after the current battle I created the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_date_func (p_ship IN VARCHAR, p_battle IN VARCHAR) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
  
  CURSOR battles_curs IS
    SELECT c.ship, b.name, b.b_date FROM battles b JOIN consequences c ON (b.name = c.battle);

  TYPE t_battles IS TABLE OF battles_curs%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  battles_tab t_battles;
  v_index BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
  v_date DATE;
  v_flag BOOLEAN;

BEGIN
  SELECT b_date INTO v_date FROM battles b JOIN consequences c ON (b.name = c.battle) WHERE battle = p_battle AND ship = p_ship;

  FOR record IN battles_curs LOOP
    v_index := v_index + 1;
    batalii_tab(v_index).ship := record.ship;
    batalii_tab(v_index).name := record.name;
    batalii_tab(v_index).b_date := record.b_date;
  END LOOP;
  
  FOR i IN battles_tab.FIRST..battles_tab.LAST LOOP
    IF battles_tab(i).ship = p_ship AND battles_tab(i).name = p_battle AND battles_tab(i).b_date > v_date THEN
      v_flag := TRUE;
      RETURN v_flag;
    ELSE
      v_flag := FALSE;
      RETURN v_flag;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END check_date_func;
```

The function runs with no errors.
After that I created the trigger where I call the function. I created a compound trigger in order to avoid the mutating table error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_result_trigg
  FOR UPDATE OF result ON consequences COMPOUND TRIGGER
  TYPE t_consequences IS TABLE OF consequences%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  consequences_tab t_consequences;
  v_index BINARY_INTEGER := 0;

AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
  v_index := v_index + 1;
  consecinte_tab(v_index).ship := :NEW.ship;
  consecinte_tab(v_index).battle := :NEW.battle;
  consecinte_tab(v_index).result := :NEW.result;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS 
BEGIN
  FOR i IN consequences_tab.First..consequences_tab.LAST LOOP
    IF check_date_func(:OLD.ship, :OLD.battle) = FALSE AND :NEW.result = 'destroyed' THEN
      UPDATE consequences
      SET result= :OLD.result
      WHERE :OLD.ship= :NEW.ship AND :OLD.battle = :NEW.battle;
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500, 'Nu poti actualiza!');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
```

The only problem is that I can't use :OLD and :NEW in AFTER STATEMENT. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_result_trigg
  FOR UPDATE OF result ON consequences
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  TYPE t_consequences IS TABLE OF consequences%ROWTYPE;
  v_cons t_consequences := t_consequences();
AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.result = 'destroyed' THEN
    v_cons.EXTEND;
    v_cons(v_cons.COUNT).ship := :NEW.ship;
    v_cons(v_cons.COUNT).battle := :NEW.battle;
    v_cons(v_cons.COUNT).result := :NEW.result;
  END IF;
END AFTER EACH ROW;
AFTER STATEMENT IS
  v_rn PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_cons.COUNT LOOP
    SELECT rn
    INTO   v_rn
    FROM   (
             SELECT c.battle,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.b_date DESC) AS rn
             FROM   consequences c
                    INNER JOIN battles b
                    ON (c.battle = b.name)
             WHERE  c.ship = v_cons(i).ship
           ) c
    WHERE  battle = v_cons(i).battle;
         
    IF v_rn > 1 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500, 'Nu poti actualiza!');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

Which if you try:

```
UPDATE consequences
SET   result = 'destroyed'
WHERE ship   = 'ShipX'
AND   battle = 'Battle1';
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> ORA-20500: Nu poti actualiza!
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_XOXAMEWVYHYVRZLDYCFN.UPDATE_RESULT_TRIGG", line 30
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_XOXAMEWVYHYVRZLDYCFN.UPDATE_RESULT_TRIGG'
> ```

and because an exception was raised then the transaction is rolled back (you do not need to manually try to reset the values).

But if you use:

```
UPDATE consequences
SET   result = 'destroyed'
WHERE ship   = 'ShipX'
AND   battle = 'Battle2';
```

Then the row is updated.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cAVO1YK3)

Comment: Thanks for the complex answer. I have some questions:  **1.** Why do we need to initialize the TYPE TABLE  `v_cons t_consequences := t_consequences()` ? I coded similar triggers without initializing the TYPE TABLE and everything works fine.    **2.** Why do we need to **EXTEND** the TYPE TABLE after we put something in it `v_cons.EXTEND`  ?                              
     I saw other similar problems where **EXTEND** wasn't used. **3.** Why does it end with an error when I write `FOR i IN v_cons.FIRST..v_cons.LAST LOOP` instead of  ` FOR i IN 1 .. v_cons.COUNT LOOP` ?

Comment: @crpgdr You used an associative array with an `INDEX BY` clause and I used an non-associative array. Non-associative arrays need to be initialised, extended, etc and are typically dense (so have elements from 1 ... COUNT) whereas associative arrays can be sparse (you can skip indexes). You could use an associative array (which is almost identical to my answer [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_pcGC8-A)) but for a dense collection I opted for a non-associative array.

Comment: @crpgdr You can also do it without loops [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/amMDlF73); however, it does require creating the collection in the SQL scope (rather than PL/SQL) and for that you cannot use associative arrays as they are only created in a PL/SQL scope.